# How can I make my Netgear WPN824V2 router more secure?

Tags: windows-xp, router, firewall

I realize, in the research I have done so far, that the memory to import into this router is too low to run any custom firmware, it is updated to the current newest firmware.

But my problem is that I have security needs, and it seems to me, it would be better to offload those into the router, rather than drain CPU/memory/bandwidth having the PC handle them.

For example, I am using this simple PHP class to help detect DDoS attacks, and if it works, it will generate a list of IP addresses that will be blacklisted from viewing my site, which is fine. But I'd love to somehow import this list to the router, and therefore block any person in that list from viewing any of the open ports on my PC/server.

Now I know that the router can block sites/domains for outgoing, but not sure how to block specific IP addresses from accessing my router/network.

There is an option to block access to specific services, but the program/ports aren't services in the list.

So my end goal is to have the router constantly updated by some PHP script of the latest IP addresses to block.

I want to do something like how PeerBlock/PeerGuardian works, in blocking access to my network, but for the whole router.

I looked at using DD-WRT or Tomato but my model isn't covered.

Yes I could run software to be firewalls etc, but those take extra cpu/memory cycles, and I'd rather have the PC/server just focus on the game/web it is managing/delivering, than also the load of being a software based firewall.

I know windows has some TCP/IP filtering, but not sure how updateable that is, and I don't want to screw with my PC too much.

I am running Windows XP Professional SP3, and I am dual booting with Pinguy OS. I love Linux, but this game I play and plan to serve only works on Windows.

Any suggestions to improve my router or use it better? I want to find cheap and smart ways to make it more secure without having to spend a lot of money that I don't have.

Comment: Was it hard to install/setup? From what I read the WPN824v2 is not supported. Any suggested install steps, and thank you.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Mine is actually the model WNR834Bv2. I can never remember all these model numbers.